# Only show a total if a subtotal exists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am new to formulas, so hopefully I will write this clearly enough to be understood.

I need to calculate a running balance, but only want a value to display if the row has a subtotal. In the subtotal column (column V) I have the formula `=sum (xx:xx)`. That subtotal is to be subtracted from a starting balance, then each row from the remaining balance as the user completes rows (each row contains expenses by date). I have searched online, and found several formula options, but none leave the 'balance' column blank. What formula can I use to only show the “balance” if the “expenditures Subtotal” contains data (other than the formula).

In the screenshot below the formulas in column X are the formulas I entered in W6 and W7 in hopes of the field being blank if the Expenditures Subtotal is blank (column V).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

Use this:

`=IF(V6="", "", W5-V6)`